# Set default boot disk to USB on macmini with T2 chip

Tags: usb, startup, mac-mini, t2

I need to setup boot always from USB stick.

I can boot it from USB by pressing Alt and selecting specific source. Buy how to do it permanently? Is is possible?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Go through the Apple Support document, [How to select a different startup disk](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202796).

Comment: Did you try holding down the control key before making your selection? You should see the straight arrow turn into a circular arrow.